# CFSetGetCount crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, usb, hid

I'm writing a Mac application that interfaces with a USB HID device. To get started I'm trying to print out how many devices were found that match the specifications of my device.

```
//Create a HID Manager
IOHIDManagerRef hidManager = IOHIDManagerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);

//Create a dictionary and limit it to the uPPT
CFMutableDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable (kCFAllocatorDefault, 1, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                                         &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
CFDictionarySetValue(dict, CFSTR("VendorID"), CFSTR("0x04D8"));
CFDictionarySetValue(dict, CFSTR("ProductID"), CFSTR("0x0054"));
IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching(hidManager, dict);

CFSetRef devSet = IOHIDManagerCopyDevices (hidManager);
CFIndex numDevices = CFSetGetCount(devSet);
NSLog(@"%ld uPPTs found", numDevices);
```

Unfortunately this crashes at CFSetGetCount(devSet). As far as I can tell I'm using this correctly, but the application hangs and I see "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1, Address=0x0)". Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Well what's your stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`devSet` is `NULL` (as evidenced in your crash by `Address=0x0`.) You must *always* test for `NULL` when getting or creating a `CFTypeRef` in Core Foundation because Apple's APIs don't do it and will usually crash if passed `NULL`.

As well, this isn't the cause of the crash, but you must make sure to release (with `CFRelease()`) `CFTypeRef`s you create, copy, or retain, as ARC does not do it for you. And as previously stated, you must check for `NULL` before calling `CFRelease()` because a crash will happen otherwise.

Comment: devSet was, in fact NULL, so it no longer crashes. Thank you! Unfortunately it is NULL whether my device is plugged in or not, which means I must be doing something else wrong, but thanks for fixing this bit.

Comment: @Nick: You probably need to set your vendor ID and device ID to CFNumbers rather than CFStrings. I'd also change the keys to `kIOHIDVendorIDKey` and `kIOHIDProductIDKey`.

Comment: Oh, thank you for that. devSet is never null anymore, instead it's always reporting 7 devices found, whether I have my one plugged in or not haha. Guessing the filtering isn't working correctly

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the EXC_BAD_ACCESS is that you haven't defined an entitlement for USB hardware access in your App Sandbox. You can do it by activating the checkbox for USB - Hardware in your: target settings -> tab: Capabilities.

[image: Activate USB hardware access (entitlement)]

source: [Apple Docs - Enabling Hardware Access](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW11)